# Tabela populada via banco vindo com campo vazio

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

estou populando uma tabela via um `select` que tenho no meu arquivo `selectUser.php`.

**selectUser.php:**

```
<?php
require "conexaoBD.php"; 
$nome = $_GET["nome"];
try {           
    $pdo = new PDO($server, $dbuser, $dbpass);
    $sql = "SELECT `nome`, `email`, `nascimento`, `data_criacao` FROM `usuarios` WHERE `nome` like  ? ";
    $stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
    $nome = $nome."%";
    $stmt->bindParam(1, $nome, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->execute();
    $result = $stmt->fetchAll();

    foreach($result as $r) {    
        $nascimento = date('d/m/Y', strtotime(str_replace("-","/",$r["nascimento"])));  
        echo "<tr>
        <td>$r[nome]<td/>
        <td>$r[email]</td>
        <td>$nascimento</td>
        <td>$r[data_criacao]</td>
        </tr>";           
    }
}
catch(PDOException $ex) {
    echo "Error: ".$ex->getMessage();
}
?>
```

Faço um `get` via `ajax` com o arquivo `main.js` para conseguir obter o resultado.

**main.js:**

```
var buscaUser = function() {
    var nome = $("#nome").val();
    $.ajax({
        url: "http://127.0.0.1:3000/projeto1/pdo/selectUser.php?nome=" + nome,
        type: 'GET',
        success: function(data) {
            $("#corpo").append(data);
        }
    });
};

$('#buscar').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#corpo').children().remove();
    buscaUser();
});

/*$("#nome").on('input', function(){
     if($(this).val().length > 2 ){         
        buscaUser(); 
     }    
});*/
```

E no meu arquivo `index.php` tenho a tabela criada da seguinte maneira:

**index.php:**

```
<table class="table">
   <thead>
      <tr>
         <th scope="col">Nome</th>
         <th scope="col">E-mail</th>
         <th scope="col">Data de Nascimento</th>
         <th scope="col">Data de Criação</th>
      </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody id="corpo">
      <tr>
         <td>Nome</td>
         <td>Email</td>
         <td>Data nascimento</td>
         <td>Data Criacao</td>
      </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

Fazendo um teste, procurando por exemplo pelo meu nome, obtenho o seguinte resultado:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Tenho sucesso na consulta mas é gerado um `<td>` vazio quebrando assim o layout.
Alguém sabe aonde estou errando?

Comment: Fechaste mal o td -> "<td>$r[nome]<td/>" para: "<td>$r[nome]</td>" no ficheiro selectUser.php

Comment: Que besteira de erro! Obrigado @White, era isso mesmo ;D

Comment: Continua, siga :)

Comment: Coloque como resposta para eu marcar como certa.

Comment: Erro de digitação é uma barra!!! :) melhor é remover a pergunta.

Comment: Já está xD pode ser que não liguem e a deixem como certa :)

Comment: @JorgeMatheus o rei do PHP !! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A tag `<td>` está mal fechada no ficheiro selectUser.php.
Copia isto para o teu código:

```
<tr>
<td>$r[nome]</td>
<td>$r[email]</td>
<td>$nascimento</td>
<td>$r[data_criacao]</td>
</tr>
```